# How to add states into country show in treeview from JSON javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bootstrap-4

Thinking to merch states into country from json to make it tree view and show in html
expected output:
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aceBT.png)
below is my code

`<div  id="data-output" class="panel-group col-md-3" id="accordion">`

```
            fetch("countries.json")
            .then(function(response){
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(countries){
                let placeholder = document.querySelector("#data-output");
                let out = "";
                for(let country of countries){
                    out += 
                    `   <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#${country.country}" >${country.country}</a>
                        </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="${country.country}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">${country.states}</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>`
                    ;
                }
                placeholder.innerHTML = out;
            });
```

Here is the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AWO3.png)

Comment: out +=`<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#${country.country}" >${country.country}</a>
</div>
<div id="${country.country}" class="panel-collapse collapse">`
for(let i=0;i<country.states.length;i++){
console.log(country.states[i]);
out+=`<div class="panel-body">${country.states[i]}</div>}
out+=`</div></div>` ;

Comment: Which part of this do you consider to be jQuery ?

Comment: What does `countries.json` look like ?

Comment: Actually now I am looking for tree view menu data table, which means that can click on the tree structure menu and the data will change according when click on the tree view menu